# Actionmailer #deliver_now in Rails 4 is not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, actionmailer

I am trying to send email using typical gmail smtp Configurations. Here is my actionmailer config from development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "587",
    domain: "gmail.com",
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["DEV_EMAIL"],
    password: ENV["DEV_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Mine Application mailer

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: ENV["DEV_EMAIL"]
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

and the mailer

```
class Reporter < ApplicationMailer
  def message
    mail(to: "softmfq@gmail.com", subject: "Simple email")
  end
end
```

This how I am sending emails

```
Reporter.message.deliver_now!
```

But #deliver_now! is left application to not responding state. Am I missing something ?

Comment: What's in the `development.log` when `deliver_now!` is called?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy nothing, it just kept waiting and waiting. if I try it in controller then server throws not responding exception but on rails console it just get stuck.